# Java - What is a meaning of Combination of access modifier and class name

Tags: java

This is a [linked list implementation code in Java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvc2D.jpg). I am new for Java and therefore unable to understand why `private ListNode head` define and what is the concept of the declaration.

ListNode is class name and head could be a variable name? I have issue with `'private ListNode head'` and `private ListNode next'`

```
public class linkedlist{

    public static void main(String[] args){

    }
    private ListNode Head;

    public class ListNode(){
        private int data;
        private ListNode Next;

    Public ListNode(int data){
        this.data=data;
        this.next=null;
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the tags, you  are asking a question about 4 different programming languages.  That is Too Broad.   Even if this was Just about Java, it is "Too Broad".   I think you should start by reading a good tutorial on Java, or a beginner's textbook.  For example, the Oracle Java Tutorial.

Comment: could you please tell me, what is a concept  of declaration? Actually i have no enough time to do from begining.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `private` modifier indicates that the member is only accessible from within the same class (and nested classes, if any).  Without the modifier, it would be accessible from other classes in the same package (using `obj.head` if `obj` is an instance of the class).

- [Declaring Member Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) (search for *Access Modifiers*)
- [JLS §8.2, Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.2)